# reading data using java servlet in sencha touch

Tags: java, json, servlets

i've created this servlet to connect to database and retrieve data then output them in JSON format.
this is the servlet :

```
public class ConnectServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {      


    res.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        JSONArray relatedWorkordersArray = new JSONArray();
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con=(Connection)               DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users","root","");  
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from user");


            JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject();
            st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            rs = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery("select * from user");
            while (rs.next()) {

            String nom = rs.getString("nom");
            String prenom = rs.getString("prenom");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");

            JSONObject Object = new JSONObject();
            Object.put("nom", nom);
            Object.put("prenom", prenom);
            Object.put("age", age);
            relatedWorkordersArray.put(Object);
            }
            jObj.put("data",relatedWorkordersArray.toString());
            jObj.put("Success", true);

            rs.close ();
            st.close ();
            con.close();
            //print JSON object 
            out.print(jObj);
```

Now, In my sencha touch project i've created a JSON-P STORE and i've putted in his url the name of this servlet : ConnectServlet.java but i have an error: unable to load data  using the supplied configuration. open in browser : ConnectServlet.java

how can I do to make this proxy using the servlet to get data from database?

Answer (score 0):

you may find your solution here.[click here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121378-Datastore-quot-Unable-to-load-data-using-the-supplied-configuration-quot)